# how to Integrate TFS 2010 with Cruise Control . Net 1.44

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

how do i integrate TFS 2010 with Cruise control . Net 1.44, i just added ccnet.vsts.plugin.dll in server folder but it didnot worked and i got the below error message

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.Vsts.GetModifications(IIntegrationResult from, IIntegrationResult to)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.QuietPeriod.GetModifications(ISourceControl sourceControl, IIntegrationResult lastBuild, IIntegrationResult thisBuild)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.IntegrationRunner.GetModifications(IIntegrationResult from, IIntegrationResult to)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.IntegrationRunner.Integrate(IntegrationRequest request)
```

```
WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
```

even i tried to change from 64 bit to 32 bit using below command

```
corflags.exe /32bit+ C:/CruiseControl.NET/server/ccservice.exe
```

but it didnot worked. Please can any one help me here.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and setting it to 32bit worked for me... I did have to restart the service before it worked however. Have you done a restart yet?

Answer (score 0):

You need install team explorer 2008 on your build machine. it should support TFS 2010.